# Linux get CPU cache hit ratio

Tags: linux, cache, central-processing-unit

AFAIK a lot of modern CPUs have counters for memory cache misses/hits.

Is there an API/program which can query this? Is there a way to reset the counters?

I'm interested in any generic or CPU specific program.

Note: I'm aware of cachegrind, but that's a simulation, and not the actual CPU counter.

Comment: I am almost certain I saw something of this type somewhere but can't remember now. I will keep looking. However, what comes to mind for an individual pid or process or command is 'perf stat <command>'. That is quite exhaustive.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I plundered some more resources and appears like for CPU cache hit/miss counters, we have to go for individual process or pid or tid based tracing. That is, in other words, perf and oprofile.

For example perf stat gives this.

```
 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

      3.905621 task-clock                #    0.831 CPUs utilized
             1 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec
             0 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec
           267 page-faults               #    0.068 M/sec
       379,003 cycles                    #    0.097 GHz                     [24.55%]
     1,332,419 stalled-cycles-frontend   #  351.56% frontend cycles idle    [36.65%]
 <not counted> stalled-cycles-backend
       833,177 instructions              #    2.20  insns per cycle
                                         #    1.60  stalled cycles per insn
       580,745 branches                  #  148.695 M/sec                   [95.65%]
        37,799 branch-misses             #    6.51% of all branches         [71.09%]

   0.004697863 seconds time elapsed
```

Oprofile gives the similar output but perf is pretty awesome, imo.

Other thing is, for memory banks, numastat gives you another level of detail.

```
$ numastat
                       node0
numa_hit                74263001
numa_miss                      0
numa_foreign                   0
interleave_hit             15459
local_node              74263001
other_node                     0
```

Yeah, this system is a 1 node system.

Answer (score 0):

In this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114325/356440) they talk about linux tools for profiling cache-miss:

perf:

```
$ perf stat ./yourapp
$ perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000
```

valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./yourapp
```

but also `time` that counts page faults in theory:

```
$ time -v YourProgram.exe
```

on my system it does not accept `-v` flag, I must check why